# set and clear the memory address bits

Tags: c++, c, embedded, bit-manipulation

I suppose to write a c-code to sets the third bit (0x4) and clears the seventh bit (0x40) of memory address 0x3803, but I am not sure about the values (0x4 and 0x3F) which I should make "&" and "|" to complete the operation:

```
*((char *) 0x3803) = *((char *) 0x3803) | 0x4;
*((char *) 0x3803) = *((char *) 0x3803) & 0x3F;
```

I just want to assure about my values that either its right or there could be other alternatives to these values

Comment: `0x4` is correct, `0x3F` should be `0xBF`.

Comment: you need a volatile in that typecast otherwise the compiler might optimize it out and/or not actually touch memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear a bit, you need to `AND` with a complement value, i.e. the inversion of `0x40`, which is `0xBF`. You can have the compiler compute the value for you by using `~`.

Note that you can use `&=` and `|=` for that:

```
*((char *) 0x3803) |= 0x04;
*((char *) 0x3803) &= ~0x40;
```

Comment: Are theses values are independent of memory addresses? I mean any time that I want to set the 0x4 bit of any address I should "|" it with 0x4 and every time I want to clear the 7th bit of any address I should "&" it with 0xBF

Comment: @alikaveh Correct, the bit masks are independent of the addresses to which you apply them.

Comment: That’s ok, could you please tell me about toggling (if set clear and if clear set) of this memory address for example on 0x02 and 0x10 bits?

Comment: @alikaveh Toggling is achieved by applying `XOR`, i.e. `*((char *) 0x3803) ^= 0x10;`

Comment: As @dwelch mentioned, you need a volatile in the type cast or you'll find the compiler optimising stuff away (`*(volatile char *)0x3803`).

Answer (score 1):

The way I would write this is as follows:

```
*((char *) 0x3803) = *((char *) 0x3803) | 0x4;  // Unchanged from what you already had
*((char *) 0x3803) = *((char *) 0x3803) & ~0x40;
```

To clear a specific bit I like to use bitwise negation with bitwise and, to avoid the problem you have demonstrated. You know you want to clear the bit that is masked by 0x40, so bitwise negation will flip all the bits and result in 0xbf... The correct value to clear bit 0x40...

Answer (score 1):

I would let the compiler figure out the bit masks and only give it the bit numbers:

```
*((char *) 0x3803) |= (1 << 2);
*((char *) 0x3803) &= ~(1 << 6);
```

Note that the third and seventh bit are actually bits 2 and 6, since numbering starts at zero.

Also note that in real software the pointer and the bits or bit masks should be named, as such magic numbers in the middle of code are frowned upon.

Comment: @ starblue, bit 3 is RUN bit and will activate the timer (whenever its high) and the bit 7 is EXP interrupt, that by reading the control byte the EXP it will be rested